# django autofil with the pk page

Tags: python, html, django

I would like to add documents to an employee's profile in a form but I would like the form to automatically select the id or the (pk) of the employee's page, anyone have the solution?

view.py

```
def createDocument(request):
forms = documentForm()

if request.method == 'POST':
    forms = documentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if forms.is_valid():
        forms.save()
        return redirect('/employe')

context = {'forms':forms}
return render(request, 'accounts/document_form.html', context)
```

[add document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh697.png)
[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxk8M.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, read how to work with Django-GCBV, more here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView

in your case:

```
# views.py
def createDocument(UpdateView):
    model = Employer
    form_class = documentForm
    sucsess_url = '/employe'
    template_name = 'accounts/document_form.html'
```

If you named template like `employe_form.html` you can avoid `template_name` attribute.

don't forget to setup `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ... # other urls
    path('add_document_to_employe/<pk>', createDocument.as_view(), name='create_document'),
    ... # other urls
]
```

Comment: I tried this way but now I have this error message? The view accounts.decorators.wrapper_func didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the Pk as part of context to the employee profile page. Pull this context data when performing the Add action.